# how to join multi tables using sqlalchemy on flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on flask server using sqlalchemy.

I've got a issue with join query.

I wanna get result same as below query which will return matches user joined team and after joined date.

```
SELECT *
            FROM `match` as m
            join (
                SELECT  team_id,update_date
                FROM team_member
                where user_id = 108
            ) as mt
            on m.request_team_id = mt.team_id
            or m.against_team_id = mt.team_id
            WHERE mt.update_date <= timestamp(m.match_date,m.match_start_time)
            AND (m.match_status = 'PROGRESS' OR m.match_status= 'DONE')
            order by m.match_date desc
```

but when I use subqueryload like below

```
Match.query.options(subqueryload(Match.team)).filter(TeamMember.user_id == user.user_id)\
            .filter(or_(Match.match_status == 'PROGRESS', Match.match_status == 'DONE')).\
            filter(TeamMember.update_date <= func.timestamp(Match.match_date, Match.match_start_time))\
            .order_by(Match.match_date.desc()).all()
```

This executed query twice when I turn on query debug and wrong results.

I wanna execute only one query for this result.

how to solve this issue?

if there is no solution, should I use raw query but it can not be bind to model right?

Here is my models.

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user'
user_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(200), unique=True)
team = db.relationship('Teams', secondary='team_member', primaryjoin=user_id == TeamMember.user_id)

class Teams(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'teams'

team_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
team_name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(100),nullable=False, index=True)


class TeamMember(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'team_member'
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'), primary_key=True)
team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.team_id'), primary_key=True)
role_name = db.Column(db.Enum("M","P"), default="P")
user = db.relationship('User', backref=backref("team_member", cascade="all, delete"))
team = db.relationship('Teams', backref=backref("team_member", cascade="all, delete"))
update_date = db.Column(db.DATETIME(), default=datetime.now())


class Match(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'match'
match_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
mc_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
request_team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.team_id'))
request_team_name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(100))
against_team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.team_id'), nullable=True)
team = db.relationship('Teams', foreign_keys=[request_team_id, against_team_id], backref="matches", uselist=False,
                       primaryjoin="or_(Teams.team_id==Match.request_team_id, Teams.team_id==Match.against_team_id)")
```